# AWS Lambda Node ES6 common JS issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, serverless

Using `nodejs18.x` runtime in AWS Lambda using Serverless I have an issue with ES6 and Common JS.

When not setting `type: module` in `package.json` Lambda complains about using `import` statements outside of the `module.export`

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

But when I do set the `type` to `module` in `package.json` it complains that I am using `required`. Which I am not doing, but the `s_tag_file.js` file which is created by Serverless does contain `required`

```
{
    "errorType": "ReferenceError",
    "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead\nThis file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains \"type\": \"module\". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.",
    "stack": [
        "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
        "This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains \"type\": \"module\". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.",
        "    at file:///var/task/s_tag_file.js:2:21",
        "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)"
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what could I be doing differently?

Here is my full code:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.391.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1437.0"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

`serverless.yaml`:

```
org: OUR_ORG
app: OUR_APP
service: OUR_SERVICE

frameworkVersion: '3'


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  region: us-east-1 # Required for using CloudFront, region does not matter though (it runs at the CF edge location anyways)
  iamRoleStatements:
  cloudFront:
    cachePolicies:
      cdnCachePolicy:
        MinTTL: 0
        MaxTTL: 5184001
        DefaultTTL: 5184000
        ParametersInCacheKeyAndForwardedToOrigin:
          CookiesConfig:
            CookieBehavior:
              none
          EnableAcceptEncodingBrotli: true
          EnableAcceptEncodingGzip: true
          HeadersConfig:
            HeaderBehavior: none
          QueryStringsConfig:
            QueryStringBehavior: none

custom:
  origin: 'ORIGIN_URL'
  path: 'build'

functions:
  tag-file:
    handler: index.tagFile
    events:
      - cloudFront:
          eventType: viewer-response
          origin:
            DomainName: ${self:custom.origin}
            OriginPath: /${self:custom.path}
            CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: match-viewer
          cachePolicy:
            name: cdnCachePolicy
```

`index.js`:

```
import { S3Client, PutObjectTaggingCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

export async function tagFile(event, context, callback) {
  const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;

  const client = new S3Client({ region: "eu-west-1"});
  const input = {
    Bucket: "BUCKET_NAME",
    Key: event.Records[0].cf.request.uri,
    Tagging: {
      TagSet: [
        {
          Key: "requestTime",
          Value: Date.now().toString(),
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  const command = new PutObjectTaggingCommand(input);
  const S3response = await client.send(command);
  console.log(S3response);

  callback(null, response);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `org` key (line 1) in your `serverless.yml` file, you are using Serverless Dashboard plugin.

This plugin do not have ES6 support (which is required for having `import` statements). Refer to https://github.com/serverless/dashboard-plugin/issues/564 for more details.

On a site note, Serverless Dashboard is being depreciated in favour of [Serverless Console](https://console.serverless.com/), which comes with ES6 support.

So if you need to support ESM:

1. Stop using Serverless Dashboard (since this plugin has been deprecated)
2. Replace Serverless Dashboard with Serverless Console